# Scala map list element to a value calculated from previous elements

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list of string elements in Scala:

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c")
```

Is there any concise way to construct another list, in which each i-th element will be constructed from 0..i-th elements of list (in my case it is `list.take(i + 1).mkString("|")` )

```
val calculatedLst = briefFunc(list) // List("a", "a|b", "a|b|c")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for is `scan`, which accumulates a collection of intermediate cumulative results using a start value.

Very quick try with `scanLeft`. Will fail if the list is empty.

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c")                   
list.drop(1).scanLeft(list.head) {
  case (r, c) => r + "|" + c
}                                              
//> res0: List[String] = List(a, a|b, a|b|c)
```